# Terminology: DML "that modifies things"

Tags: sql, terminology, dml

I understand that DML technically encompasses SQL verbs which merely query but do not modify persistent data. (See, e.g., [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language) or [oracle](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:670629100346040211) or [orafaq](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_are_the_difference_between_ddl_dml_and_dcl_commands))

However, I often wish to refer to "all and only those SQL verbs which modify stored/persistent data" -- basically `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` but *not* a plain `SELECT`.  Is there an official/standardized term, or, perhaps separately, a cogent and graceful term, for this subset of DML?

Comment: Woah, I glanced at this question title and read "Demonology:  'that modifies things'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is one, sadly, from an official perspective.  Perhaps we need to make one up?

Personally, I think the term DML is misleading because the term doesn't really describe the way SELECT works, as it (usually) doesn't actually *modify* anything. It only "collects" the relational data in a different fashion in temporary space and returns a specified set of it.

So, if it was my choice, I would say that:

***DML*** *would describe INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE*

and

***DRL*** (**data retrieval language**) *would describe SELECT*.

Comment: Accepted.  While I think we'd argue ad infinitum about new terminology, I think the thrust of your answer is dead on.

Comment: Maybe we could all just agree that DML means "Data Manipulation Language" (as opposed to DDL, which is still "Data Definition Language"). :)

Answer (score 2):

DML includes `SELECT INTO` (as opposed to just `SELECT`) because it is a *synonym* for INSERTs.  There's no need to subcategorize.

After thinking about it on the way into work, I remembered that SELECT *is* used for data manipulation.  For example:

```
SELECT t.firstname +' '+ t.lastname --String concatenation
SELECT CAST(t.column AS int) --Datatype change
```

Comment: Yes, DML is the term you're looking for.

Comment: Yes and clever, but a plain SELECT can only transform data in ephemeral projections, it cannot modify the stored or persistent data, which is the intent behind my question.  I'll clarify.

Comment: @pilcrow: Modification implies persistence, but there are cases where persistence isn't required - the need is temporary.  But it is still data manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

My professor used to define them as Edits (as opposed to Reads), but I do not know of a Standard Term for IUD.

Comment: Hmm, I rather like that:  "DML Edits."

Answer (score 0):

based on CRUD: [Create, read, update and delete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete), you could just say CUD (create, update, delete).  however, I'm not sure if anyone uses that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Wikipedia article on SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL),

> The Data Manipulation Language (DML)
>   is the subset of SQL used to add,
>   update and delete data:

and the [statements discussed there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Data_manipulation) (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE, TRUNCATE, etc) are placed in a [different category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Queries) than SELECT.

So, according to Wikipedia, DML may not necessarily include SELECT.

---

According to the [SQL-92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), glancing at the table-of-contents reveals that DML does include SELECT INTO:

> ```
>      13 Data manipulation ............................................371
>
>      (...)
>
>      13.5 <select statement: single row> .............................382
>
>      (...)
> ```

The definition listed there describes `SELECT <columns> INTO ...` .